# Batch: merge pdfs with same "filename-part" and pdftk

Tags: batch-file, pdf, merge, pdftk

I want to merge some PDFs with pdftk.
To merge pdfs with pdftk you have to use

```
"pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf output file_final.pdf"
```

But I have to merge a lot of pdfs with filenames like this

```
   BCCM995_KM_1.pdf
   BCCM995_KM_2.pdf
   BCCM995_KM_3.pdf
   QREM657_KM_1.pdf
   QREM657_KM_2.pdf
   QREM657_KM_3.pdf  
   QREM657_KM_4.pdf
```

The batch-script should parse the filenames and merge all files which starts with the same filename, like BCCM995_* oder QREM657_*.

"_" is the delimiter.

I have a bash-script with this funciton, but i need a batch-script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *_KM_1
  do
    number=$( echo $file | cut -d'_' -f1 )
    files=$(ls | grep "$number")
    echo "Found Number: $number"
    pdftk $files output output/$number.pdf
    echo "Wrote merged file to: /output/$number.pdf"
done
```

Can someone help me or recommend me a website to learn batch?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `pdftk *.pdf cat ouput.pdf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I used to not answer questions that have not provided at least a small section of Batch file code, I do an exception in this case...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize (delete) "lastFile" and "fileList" variables
set "lastFile="
set "fileList="

rem Next line get the output of a "dir /B" command, that show file names *only*
rem "for /F" command execute the dir, get the output and divide each line in two "tokens" ("%%a" and "%%b")
rem with the first part before the "_" in "%%a" and the *rest* (including further "_") in "%%b"

for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B *_KM_*.*') do (

   rem If the base file name changed...
   if "%%a" neq "!lastFile!" (

      rem Process previous file list;
      rem this "if" is just to avoid process the empty list the first time
      if defined fileList (
         pdftk !fileList! output !lastFile!.pdf
      )

      rem Reinitialize the new list
      set "lastFile=%%a"
      set "fileList=%%a_%%b"

   ) else (

      rem Append this file to current list
      set "fileList=!fileList! %%a_%%b"

   )

)

rem Process the last list
pdftk !fileList! output !lastFile!.pdf
```

For further details on any command, type `help` followed by the command name, or type the command with `/?` parameter; for example: `for /?`. In particular, you should look for "Delayed Expansion" questions on this forum...

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! It works good, there is a little problem with "data-sets" with more then 10 pdfs, but I think i can fix this. Great job! Have a nice day